# Не выполняются функции вместе

Tags: python, api, index

Есть две функции.
Первая.

```
def get_all_information_bitby():
    balances = total_balance()
    bitby_list = list_of_pairs
    for pair in bitby_list:
        test = client.Market.Market_orderbook(symbol=str(pair[0])).result()
        for element in test[0]['result']:
            print(len(test[0]['result']))
            if element['side'] == 'Buy':
                pair.append(float(element['price']))
                break
        for element in test[0]['result']:
            if element['side'] == 'Sell':
                pair.append(float(element['price']))
                break
        pair.insert(0, 'bibyt')
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[2]):
                pair.insert(3, float(balance[2]))
                break
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[4]):
                pair.insert(5, float(balance[2]))
                break
    print(bitby_list)
    return bitby_list
```

Вторая.

```
def get_all_information_exmo():
    balances = find_all_balances_in_exmo()
    exmo_list = list_of_pairs
    for pair in exmo_list:
        symbols_pair = find_exmo_pairs(pair[0])
        orderbook = ExmoAPI_instance.api_query('order_book', {
        "pair": symbols_pair,
        "limit":100,
        })
        for order in orderbook[symbols_pair].items():
            if str(order[0]) == 'ask_top':
                print(order[1])
            if str(order[0]) == 'bid_top':
                print(order[1])
        pair.insert(0, 'exmo')
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[2]):
                pair.insert(3, float(balance[2]))
        for balance in balances:
            if str(balance[1]) == str(pair[4]):
                pair.insert(5, float(balance[2]))
    print(exmo_list)
    return exmo_list
```

Если их запускать отдельно.

```
get_all_information_exmo()
```

То все работает.
Но стоит их попытаться запустить вместе, как первая выполняется, а вторая падает. Не имеет значение, какой порядок.

Примеры

1. Запуск отдельно `get_all_information_bitby()`
   Output

```
[['bibyt', 'BTCUSDT', 'BTC', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 47400.0, 47400.5], ['bibyt', 'ETHUSDT', 'ETH', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 3406.8, 3406.85], ['bibyt', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 1.0893, 1.0894]]
```

**Абсолютно верный ответ. Тот, который мне нужен.**

2. Запускаю отдельно `get_all_information_exmo()`
   Output

```
[['exmo', 'BTCUSDT', 'BTC', 2.347e-05, 'USDT', 31.22294593], ['exmo', 'ETHUSDT', 'ETH', 0.00117394, 'USDT', 31.22294593], ['exmo', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 0.12317691, 'USDT', 31.22294593]]
```

**То что надо.**
Теперь, внимание!
Запускаю вместе, друг за другом

```
get_all_information_exmo()
get_all_information_bitby()
```

Output

```
[['exmo', 'BTCUSDT', 'BTC', 2.347e-05, 'USDT', 31.22294593], ['exmo', 'ETHUSDT', 'ETH', 0.00117394, 'USDT', 31.22294593], ['exmo', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 0.12317691, 'USDT', 31.22294593]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pumpetee\Desktop\work\back august 2021\Orfey_multiprotocol\bitby_test.py", line 344, in <module>
    get_all_information_bitby()
  File "c:\Users\Pumpetee\Desktop\work\back august 2021\Orfey_multiprotocol\bitby_test.py", line 141, in get_all_information_bitby
    for element in test[0]['result']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Меняю местами.

```
get_all_information_bitby()
get_all_information_exmo()
```

Output

```
[['bibyt', 'BTCUSDT', 'BTC', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 47453.5, 47454.0], ['bibyt', 'ETHUSDT', 'ETH', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 3412.3, 3412.35], ['bibyt', 'XRPUSDT', 'XRP', 0.0, 'USDT', 0.0, 1.09, 1.0901]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pumpetee\Desktop\work\back august 2021\Orfey_multiprotocol\bitby_test.py", line 344, in <module>
    get_all_information_exmo()
  File "c:\Users\Pumpetee\Desktop\work\back august 2021\Orfey_multiprotocol\bitby_test.py", line 220, in get_all_information_exmo
    for order in orderbook[symbols_pair].items():
KeyError: None
```

**Как такое возможно? Я сначала думал проблема с литералами, но нет. Эти функции просто не хотят работать вместе**

Comment: Предположу. `bitby_list = list_of_pairs` делает не копию списка, а лишь присваевает ссылку на него новому идентификатору. Меняя bitby_list или его элементы, вы меняете list_of_pairs, который потом используете как `exmo_list = list_of_pairs`

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Сейчас проверю. Попробую из словаря провернуть эту историю.

Comment: Правильный ответ. Все верно сказали. Словари развел и все пошло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Списки ссылаются на один и тот же объект. И любое действие видоизменяет объект итерации тоже.
Поэтому, самый простой путь без словарей и чтобы работало, добавить библиотеку copy

И вместо:

```
bitby_list = list_of_pairs
```

Использовать `deepcopy`:

```
bitby_list = copy.deepcopy(list_of_pairs)
```

Если обьект не содержит внутри себя другие объекты, то достаточно `copy.copy(list_of_pairs)`